# Unable to retrieve the closest element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been trying to retrieve the closest element with the following sample html and selector

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <div>
        <p data-message="hello">Hello, World</p>
        <ul>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
        <p>Try again</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to retrieve the nearest **p** element with **data-message** attribute from **li** element.

The following code returns `null`

```
var el = document.querySelector('li');
el.closest('p[data-message]');
```

Comment: Because the `<p>` is not an ancestor of `<li>`. It is a sibling of the `<li>` parent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Closest only gets parent elements, and since the `p` isn't a parent of `li`, you will want to get the closest `div` then do a `querySelector` on that like this:

```js
let el = document.querySelector('li')
let p = el.closest('div').querySelector('p[data-message]')

console.log(p.textContent)
```

```html
<div>
  <p data-message="hello">Hello, World</p>
  <ul>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
  <p>Try again</p>
</div>
```

You could replace `p[data-message]` with `:scope>p[data-message]` if you want a direct child of `div`, otherwise the querySelector will get all `p` elements with the attribute `[data-message]` and are a child of the div in some way (directly or indirectly).